# passing input and receiving output from application on docker

Tags: python, docker

I write a python script that runs an Ububtu docker. on the docker I run an application that   writes to it's stdout everything that is writen on it's stdin.
I can not find the way to forward text from the python script to the application, and receive its output. is this possible?

```
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(  image=doxker_image_name, 
                                    detach=True,
                                    name=dockername,
                                    #network_disabled=True,
                                    network_mode='host',
                                    remove=True,
                                    tty=True)

socket = container.exec_run( cmd='./MirrorText',
                                stdin=True,
                                socket=True,
                                workdir='/usr/src/ctf',
                                tty=True,
                                )[1]

socket._sock.sendall(b"abc\n")
container.wait()
```

Comment: Do you want to write in python to stdin in the docker container? So that you script can write it to stdout? What is the reason for your requirement, perhaps helps that in understanding your question...

Comment: I want to send text from the python script, throu the docker and into the application that runs on the docker. then I want to receive the output of the applciation to the python script

Comment: Can you update your application to have, say, an HTTP interface, that you can call using `requests`?  That might be simpler than trying to use the raw socket directly.